# How to set debugging working directory's default path in Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio, debugging, relative-path, working-directory

Using VS 2017.

I just spent quite a bit of time wondering why relative paths don't work when running my application in a debug session from within VS (works fine when started from CMD). Apparently the default working directory is pointing at `${ProjectDir}` instead of `${OutDir}`.

I would like to change the default path but since I lack VS knowledge I am unable to find it in the settings of the IDE.

**UPDATE:** To avoid confusion: I know about the setting inside the solution/project properties (Debugging section). I am looking for something that sets the directory whenever a new project is created or imported.

Comment: Guessing at a C++ solution.  Project > Properties > Debugging > "Working Directory" setting.   This is supposed to be discoverable, spend a lazy Friday afternoon looking at what's there.  Press F1 when a setting is mysterious.

Comment: I know about this setting and this is not it. I am talking about a setting that - whenever I create a project - makes the working directory the output one automatically.

Comment: I assume you're using a C/C++ project? Because for C#, it appears this has been fixed in VS2019. At least I never have to edit that setting any more.

Answer (score 0):

May be it is a little late to answer this question, but ...
Also I'm using VS2013 (for business reasons) but I think for VS2017 it should work in a similar way.

**My solution:**
put something like the following in your `.vcxproj` file and leave the VS-Gui property dialog as is (or turn it back to *inherit-or-standard*)

```
<PropertyGroup>
  <my_workdir>$(SolutionDir)..\runtime\$(PlatformTarget)-$(Configuration)\</my_workdir>
  <LocalDebuggerWorkingdirectory>$(my_workdir)</LocalDebuggerWorkingDirectory>
</PropertyGroup>
```

After reloading the solution you should see your settings `$(my_workdir)` in the property-dialog.
Depending on the current build config it expands to `..\runtime\x64-Debug` or so, but this is a matter of taste.

I prefer to use paths *relative* to the solution directory where ever possible.

**If you want this as a standard behaviour...**
have a look in your `.vcxproj` file (usually generated via VS->AddNewProject).
You should find there something like this:

```
<ImportGroup>
  <Import Project="$(UserRootDir)\Microsoft.Cpp.$(Platform).user.props"
        Condition="exists('$(UserRootDir)\Microsoft.Cpp.$(Platform).user.props')"
        Label="LocalAppDataPlatform" />
  . . .
```

The `$(UserRootDir)` macro expands to `%HOME%\AppData\Local\MicroSoft\MSBuild\v4.0` or so.
You can (create &) edit the `*.user.props` files there.
In your case you would put the `<LocalDebuggerWorkingDirectory>..` definition in these files -- and that's it.

For my self I do not use this method.
I use a `./props/global_definitions.props` file in the $(SolutionDirectory) which I import (using a text editor) into my `.vcxproj` files.